# Custom Admin Edit form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform

I'm having some difficulty setting up an edit form within my custom module, when i inspect i see the header "New Manufacturer", but the div which would typically be rendered with the class "page-content" is missing.[image]

I've specified the block as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Amrita\Manufacturer\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit" name="manufacturer_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**The block looks like this:**

```
<?php
namespace Amrita\Manufacturer\Block\Adminhtml\Grid;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'manufacturer_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Amrita_Manufacturer';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_grid';


        parent::_construct();

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Amrita_Manufacturer::save_manufacturer')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Manufacturer'));
            $this->buttonList->add(
                'saveandcontinue',
                [
                    'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'mage-init' => [
                            'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                -100
            );
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('save');
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Amrita_Manufacturer::delete_manufacturer')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('delete', 'label', __('Delete Manufacturer'));
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('delete');
        }
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('manufacturer_grid');
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->getModel()->getId()) {
            return __("Edit Manufacturer '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->getModel()->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return __('New Manufacturer');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    /**
     * Getter of url for "Save and Continue" button
     * tab_id will be replaced by desired by JS later
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('manufacturer/*/save', ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '']);
    }
}
```

**The `Form.php` is as follows:**

```
<?php

namespace Amrita\Manufacturer\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;

class Form extends Generic
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Init form
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('manufacturer_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Manufacturer Information'));
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('manufacturer_grid');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->getModel();

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('manufacturer_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );

        if ($model->getManufacturerId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('manufacturer_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'manufacturer_id']);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'title',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'title', 'label' => __('Manufacturer Title'), 'title' => __('Manufacturer Title'), 'required' => true]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'description',
            'editor',
            [
                'name' => 'description',
                'label' => __('Description'),
                'title' => __('Description'),
                'style' => 'height:36em',
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'is_enabled',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'name' => 'is_enabled',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => ['1' => __('Enabled'), '0' => __('Disabled')]
            ]
        );
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('is_enabled', '1');
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'is_restricted',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Product Permissions'),
                'title' => __('Product Permissions'),
                'name' => 'is_restricted',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => ['1' => __('Restricted'), '0' => __('Unrestricted')]
            ]
        );
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('is_restricted', '1');
        }

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

**The new action is as follows:**

```
<?php
namespace Amrita\Manufacturer\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward $resultForward */
        $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
        return $resultForward->forward('edit');
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Amrita_Manufacturer::save_manufacturer');
    }
}
```

**The edit action is as follows:**

```
<?php
namespace Amrita\Manufacturer\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Amrita_Manufacturer::save_manufacturer');
    }

    /**
     * Init actions
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        // load layout, set active menu and breadcrumbs
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Amrita_Manufacturer::amrita_manufacturergrid')
        ->addBreadcrumb(__('Manufacturers'), __('Manufacturers'))
        ->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Manufacturers'), __('Manage Manufacturers'));
        return $resultPage;
    }

    /**
     * Edit Blog post
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('manufacturer_id');
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Amrita\Manufacturer\Model\Manufacturer');

        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This manufacturer no longer exists.'));
                /** \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
        }

        $data = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        $this->_coreRegistry->register('manufacturer_grid', $model);

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_initAction();
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(
            $id ? __('Edit Manufacturer') : __('New Manufacturer'),
            $id ? __('Edit Manufacturer') : __('New Manufacturer')
        );
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Manufacturers'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()
            ->prepend($model->getId() ? $model->getTitle() : __('New Manufacturer'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. the method `getManufacturerId()` in the `form.php`, where/how is
   this defined.
2. what should I add to the core registry? Is it the `Cache_tag` as
   defined in the model `Manufacturer.php`?
   `$this->_coreRegistry->registry('manufacturer_grid');`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing **layout** defined in your xml file.
set **`layout="admin-2columns-left"`** in your page tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="admin-2columns-left">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Amrita\Manufacturer\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit" name="manufacturer_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This hasn't resolved the problem. My assumption was that an admin layout would be specified by default. Also, in the example i'm following, no layout is specified.  https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-part-5-adminhtml/

Answer (score 0):

Because of `$this->_coreRegistry->register()`, invalid core registry your form is not loading. Your core registry should be your model class, like `$this->_coreRegistry->register(modulename_modelclass);`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your layout configuration file has the same namespace name with route front name. For example: your route front name is manufacturer, and your layout configuration file name is manufacturer_grid_edit.

Comment: waht is configuration file?